# SQL How to count one column when another column is distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
fin_aid_status | student_number
---------------|---------------
YES            | 111222
YES            | 111222
               | 111333
YES            | 111444
```

I want to count the number of `fin_aid_status` but not double count rows where student_number is duplicated. So the result I would like from this table would be 2. Not 3 because `111222` is in the table twice. There are many other columns in the table as well though so just looking for unique values in the table will not work.

**EDIT**: This is *Oracle*.

For example I am using code like this already:

```
select count(*), count(distinct student_number) from table
```

So for  third column I would want to count the number on financial aid with unique student numbers.

So my expected output would be:

```
count(*) | count(distinct student_number) | count_fin_aid
4        | 3                              | 2
```

Comment: pls. mark the DB name (mysql, mssql, orcle, etc) which you are using

Comment: also add your expected result, code you have tried.

Comment: I edited my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case statement to evaluate the student_number when the fin_aid_status is not null; then count the distinct values.

```
SELECT count(Distinct case when fin_aid_status is not null 
                           then student_number end)  as Distinct_Student
FROM tbl;
```

Result using sample data: 2

Given Oracle:

```
With cte (fin_aid_status, student_number) as (
SELECT 'YES'            , 111222 from dual union all
SELECT 'YES'            , 111222 from dual union all
SELECT ''               , 111333 from dual union all
SELECT 'YES'            , 111444 from dual )
SELECT count(Distinct case when fin_aid_status is not null 
                           then student_number end) as DistinctStudentCnt 
FROM  cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL you can write something as follows, if all you want is count

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT student_number) FROM your_table WHERE fin_aid_status = 'YES';
```

Comment: I can't do this because then other counts I am doing would be ruined because of fin_aid_status.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here, add some expected results but:

```
SELECT fin_aid_status,
       COUNT(DISTINCT student_number)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY fin_aid_status;
```

Will give you count of distinct values in the student_number column for each value in the fin_aid_status column